# How do I force Wordpress to show most recent version of images in the media library?

Tags: media, cache, media-library

My workflow is sometimes the following:

1. Delete many images from the media library at once (named for example, `01.jpg`, `02.jpg`, `03.jpg`...).
2. Re-upload a series of images with the same file names (`01.jpg`, `02.jpg`, `03.jpg`...).

The media library retains and display shows the old images as thumbnails and previews, even though they are deleted.

Obviously this problem is avoidable by adding images with distinct file names, but I wondered if there were some better way that works regardless of naming convention. Or something else that I'm completely missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure that's not just your browser caching the images? CTRL + F5'ed?

Comment: @t31os Thanks for your response. I'm sure it is just my browser caching the images. But (I should have specified) I'm not the only user. I'd prefer not to have to tell my users to refresh every time they delete something or the clunkiness of building in a page refresh as part of image deletion.

Comment: +1'ed both the current answers(with my last two votes for the day), using a query variable is a good method for cache busting.. :)

Comment: Isn't there also a WP plugin to force regenerate thumbnails?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. 

I'm ok on the CMS front-end. There's no way to cache bust the media gallery/library without editing the core though, right?

mod_expires might be my best bet.

Answer (score 4):

> @t31os Thanks for your response. I'm
>   sure it is just my browser caching the
>   images. But (I should have specified)
>   I'm not the only user. I'd prefer not
>   to have to tell my users to refresh
>   every time they delete something or
>   the clunkiness of building in a page
>   refresh as part of image deletion.

But, that's just why we have browser caching — to prevent the same image from loading everytime we call it again. The browser sees it as the same image.

You can make a little workaround by calling the image like this:
http://yoursite.com/images/01.jpg?v1 and http://yoursite.com/images/01.jpg?v2 - this would load the same image 2 times.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is the trick WP uses with enqueues when you specify a version of script/style: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 3):

This is a browser cache issue, *not* a WordPress media library issue.  The reason you see the old images in the media gallery is because you used the same file name and your browser is trying to save time and bandwidth by loading the versions it already has.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

### Cache Busting

Add a query variable (`?v=5`) to the end of your image names as used on the front-end.  This won't affect the media gallery ... but it will prevent people from seeing cached versions of old images on the front-end.  For reference, this is the same method we use in WP core to force the browser to re-download updated JavaScript files.

### mod_expires

You can tell your server (Apache) to set a custom "expires" date and time for different images either based on the extension (all jpg or png files) or the filename, if you want to get really granular.  This is more of an advanced trick, but you can use this to immediately flush everyone's cache whenever you upload new images.

- [How to Set an Expires Header in Apache](http://www.justinbritten.com/work/2008/12/how-to-set-an-expires-header-in-apache/) (using `ExpiresByType`)
- [Apache Module mod_expires reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's the cache issue. You can clear the browser cache to see changes. If your're using any Cache plug-in in your WordPress site then also clear that.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! How is this answer different from @EAMann? This seems to be exactly the same answer but with less information, if its different please consider adding more information. As it stands this is a copy of @EAMann answer.